# ZF3 MVC Zend\Authentication as a Service Factory

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth, zend-framework3, zf3

I'm trying to adapt my ZF2 `User` module to ZF3 MVC. It has an authentication service manager that is called in the `onBootsrap` function inside the `Module` class for every request (i.e. page loading) to check if the user is authenticated.

As `serviceLocator` and `ServiceAware` are not available anymore I'm trying to create an `AuthenticationServiceFactory` but I do not succeed yet. Would you have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong and how I could do it with ZF3 ?

**Here is a simplified version of my `module/User/config.module.config.php` file**

```php
namespace User;

use ...

return [
    'router' => [...],
    'controllers' => [...],
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            Service\AuthenticationServiceFactory::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

**Here is my `module/User/src/Service/AuthenticationServiceFactory.php` file**

```php
namespace User\Service;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter as DbAdapter;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable\CredentialTreatmentAdapter as AuthAdapter;
use Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session as Storage;

class AuthenticationServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $controllerPluginManager = $container;
        $serviceManager = $controllerPluginManager->get('ServiceManager');
        $config = $serviceManager->get('configuration');

        $dbAdapter = new DbAdapter($config['db']); // Mysqli driver working in other modules

        $authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter);
        $authAdapter->setTableName('user')->setIdentityColumn('username')->setCredentialColumn('password');

        $storage = new Storage();

        return new AuthenticationService($storage, $authAdapter);
    }
}
```

**Here is my `module/User/src/Module.php` file**

```php
namespace User\Service;

use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable\CredentialTreatmentAdapter;

class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $services = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $auth = $services->get(AuthenticationServiceFactory::class);

        // Returns Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationServiceFactory::setIdentity()
        // $auth is an AuthenticationServiceFactory object and not the AuthenticationService returned by its __invoke() function  
        $this->authAdapter->setIdentity('dummy_user_name');
        $this->authAdapter->setCredential('dummy_password');
        print_r($this->authAdapter->authenticate());
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I've got an ACL/Auth module written here that might help you with ideas on listeners and event strategies https://github.com/Saeven/zf3-circlical-user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, when I find the answer by myself, I post it here en case it may help someone.

**`module/User/config.module.php`**

```php
namespace User;

use Zend\Router\Http\Literal;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    'router' => [...],
    'controllers' => [...],
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            'auth-service' => Service\AuthenticationServiceFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

**`module/User/src/Service/AuthenticationServiceFactory.php`**

```php
namespace User\Service;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter as DbAdapter;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable\CredentialTreatmentAdapter as AuthAdapter;
use Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session as Storage;

class AuthenticationServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        // Get data from config files.
        $controllerPluginManager = $container;
        $serviceManager = $controllerPluginManager->get('ServiceManager');
        $config = $serviceManager->get('configuration');
        // or we can simplify these 3 lines using the following
        //$config = $container->get('configuration');

        // Configure DbAdapter with set-up information from config files.
        $dbAdapter = new DbAdapter($config['db']); // Mysqli driver working in other modules

        // Configure AuthAdapter with DbAdapter.
        // See https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-authentication/adapter/dbtable/credential-treatment/
        $authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter);
        $authAdapter->setTableName('user')->setIdentityColumn('username')->setCredentialColumn('password');

        // Configure session storage.
        $storage = new Storage();

        // Return AuthenticationService.
        return new AuthenticationService($storage, $authAdapter);
    }
}
```

**`module/User/src/Module.php`**

```php
namespace User\Service;

use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable\CredentialTreatmentAdapter;

class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        // Get the service manager.
        $services = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

        // Set event to retrieve user's identity for every request.
        $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, array($this, 'protectPage'), -100);
    }

    public function protectPage(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $match = $event->getRouteMatch();
        if (! $match) {
            // We cannot do anything without a resolved route.
            return;
        }

        // Get AuthenticationService and do the verification.
        $services = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $authService = $services->get('auth-service');

        // If user does not have an identity yet.
        if (! $authService->hasIdentity()) {
            // Do what you want like routing to login page...
        }
    }
}
```

My problem was that setting user's identity and credential was not supposed to be done here but rather in a `login()` function somewhere else. In the `Module Class` we just need to check the identity.

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted your own answer because I think it's a good one, but maybe this will improve it for the DB connexion.

You wrote that you already have a Mysqli driver working with another module. If you have a repository in this other module for the user table, you can use it and simplify your code with a custom adapter. Supposing your User repository implements `User\Model\UserRepositoryInterface`:

```
namespace User\Model;

interface UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function getUser($id);
    public function updateUser(User $user);
    // other methods...
}
```

**`Module\src\Factory\CustomAdapterFactory.php`**

```
namespace User\Factory;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use User\Adapter\CustomAdapter;
use User\Model\UserRepositoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class CustomAdapterFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        return new CustomAdapter($container->get(UserRepositoryInterface::class));
    }
}
```

Your **`AuthenticationServiceFactory`** become:

```
namespace User\Factory;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use User\Adapter\CustomAdapter;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session as SessionStorage;

class AuthenticationServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $authService = new AuthenticationService();
        $storage = new SessionStorage();
        $authService->setStorage($storage);
        $authService->setAdapter($container->get(CustomAdapter::class));
        return $authService;
    }
}
```

Register your factories: **`module/User/config.module.php`**

```
namespace User;

use User\Factory\AuthenticationServiceFactory;
use User\Factory\CustomAdapterFactory;
use User\Factory\UserRepositoryFactory;
use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;

return [
    'service_manager' => [
        'aliases' => [
            Model\UserRepositoryInterface::class => Model\UserRepository::class
        ],
        'factories' => [
            Model\UserRepository::class => UserRepositoryFactory::class,
            Adapter\CustomAdapter::class => CustomAdapterFactory::class,
            MailService::class => MailServiceFactory::class,
            AuthenticationService::class => AuthenticationServiceFactory::class,
        ]
    ],
    // etc...
];
```

Comment: You're right, it's a good suggestion to minimize redundancy and thus reduce maintenance.